# Chrome pdf contents cannot be saved after expiry?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-cache

Am on MacOS, using Chrome Version 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)

### Initial Problem

Normally when I am viewing a pdf in a chrome tab, and if I want to save the pdf for later viewing, I would choose "Save as.." from the File menu, or from right clicking on the pdf. I would try to do this rather than press the down arrow button, as that would try to reload the pdf from the server. Recently, there were a couple of files where this ("Save as ..") did not work.

1. The URL ends in .pdf, and it looks like a normal pdf file, but on selection of location and name for the "save as..", I got a "Failed - Forbidden" error, that looks suspiciously like a http 403 error to me, like it's still somehow either trying to reload the pdf from the server, or somehow the server allows transfer to my browser but not subsequently saving it (is that even possible?)
2. The URL ends in .pdf also, sort of .. there is a parameter after the .pdf .. something like "?extra=n7aaz ..", so maybe that confuses the browser into thinking it is html when I try to save it? When I try "Save as ..", it tries to save as html.

### Subsequent Observations and Conjecture

For some reason(s), I wasn't able to reach the servers earlier, but later, when I was able to, I managed to re-download both pdfs in chrome, and this time, "Save as .." worked as normal and I was able to save a local copy of each of the pdfs. I remember that I'd had those two tabs (with the pdf files) open for a few days, before the failed "Save as .." so attempts.

I'm wondering/conjecturing, could it be that Chrome has a cache time-out that is preventing the "Save as .." of the pdf files, after they have been sitting in their browser tabs for some time? So there might some kind of expiry? Even though the pdfs are still visible in the tabs?

Comment: *"The URL ends in .pdf also, sort of .. there is a parameter after the .pdf .. something like "?extra=n7aaz .."*" - Just as general info, `?` is used in HTML to pass data to a server-side script. So that link likely isn't directly connected to an actual PDF file, but to a server-side script that returns ex. PDF data to the browser.

Comment: Thanks! And any thoughts regarding some kind of cache expiry that prevents things like saving files to disk after some amount of time?

Comment: As a guess, your thoughts about Chrome requesting new data ("reloading" the PDFs) might be correct. If Chrome made a new request to the page because it decided its own cached data was out of date (which could happen after a few days) and the web server also noticed e.g. your existing session with the server had expired, the server very well might have denied you access to those resources temporarily.